# Why MapInheritedProperties() maps my entity into two tables?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm trying to map my entities following the TPC pattern.

I have an abstract base class Agent :

```
public abstract class Agent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ChangeDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string insuranceCompanyPolicyNumber { get; set; }
        public int? KeySys { get; set; }
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int? Transactionid { get; set; }
    }
```

I have a child entity Suscriber :

```
public partial class Suscriber : Agent
    {
        public int? id_federateur { get; set; }
        public string Number { get; set; }
        public bool? suivi_client { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }      
    }
```

When i try to configure the Suscriber like the following, i've noticed that the request generated by Entity Framework is wrong :

```
public class SuscriberConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Suscriber>
    {
        public SuscriberConfiguration()
        {  
            Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    m.Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
                    // Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
                    m.ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
                });
        }
    }
```

The request generated by Entity Framework is (The table Agent2 doesn't exist):

```
SELECT E'0X0X' AS "C1",
        "Extent1"."id_personne",
        "Extent1"."suivi_client",
        "Extent1"."id_federateur",
        "Extent2"."date_mod",
        "Extent2"."date_cre",
        "Extent2"."insuranceCompanyPolicyNumber",
        "Extent2"."keySys",
        "Extent2"."id_role",
        "Extent2"."statut",
        "Extent2"."vsc_transactionid",
        "Extent2"."numero_souscripteur"     
FROM "atlas"."Agent2" AS "Extent1" 
INNER JOIN "atlas"."T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR" AS "Extent2" ON
    "Extent1"."id_personne" = "Extent2"."id_personne"
```

I know that if i changed the configuration of suscriber like this, it will work

```
public class SuscriberConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Suscriber>
    {
        public SuscriberConfiguration()
        {  
            Map(m =>
                {
                    m.MapInheritedProperties();
                    // m.Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
                    Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
                    m.ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
                });
        }
    }
```

In other words, if i configure the property Number outside the scope of the method Map or i don't apply the method Property to the parameter of the lambda, it works. `(Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");)`

Could somebody explain me how the method MapInheritedProperties() works?

Why Entity Framework generate a non existing table?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because everything that you put in one *mapping fragment*...

```
Map(m => { ... })
```

...is mapped to the table that the fragment applies to. In fact it's saying: map all properties from `Agent` and property `Number` from `Subsriber` to table "T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR". EF silently assumes that the leftovers are mapped to another table it devices by naming conventions. This happens as soon as you map one property from the derived type. If you only use `MapInheritedProperties()`, all properties, including the derived ones, are mapped to the table in the mapping fragment.

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature. It's not very clear at least. Anyway, you should map other property names outside the mapping fragment, as you already found out. Of course it's it more clear if you do that in a separate statement:

```
Map(m =>
    {
        m.MapInheritedProperties();
        m.ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
    });
Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
```

Or if you like:

```
Map(m => m.MapInheritedProperties());
ToTable("T_ACTEUR_SOUSCRIPTEUR");
Property(s => s.Number).HasColumnName("numero_souscripteur");
```